# selenium web-driver chrome doesn't execute code after

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('/usr/bin/chromium-browser')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
print("driver has started")
```

it will not execute  print("driver has started") or anything after

Answer (score 0):

It is an expected behaviour as the code will be stuck on the webdriver.Chrome while the browser is open.

I suggest you do that print before starting the driver, but that really depends on what you want to do exactly. If you need to do that in parallel, at the same time, while the browser works, you would probably need threads.